# Is this regex the most efficient way of parsing my string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

First off, here are the parameters to follow in the string I allow the user to input:

- If there is a slash, it has to appear at the start of the string, nowhere else, is limited to 1, is optional and must be succeeded by [a-zA-Z].
- If there is a tilde, it has to appear after a space " ", nothing else, is optional and must be succeeded by [a-zA-Z]. Also, this expression is limited to 2. (ie: ~exa ~mple is passed but ~exa ~mp ~le is not passed)
- The slash followed by a word is an instruction, like /get or /post.
- The tilde followed by a word is a parameter like ~now or ~later.

String format:

- [instruction] (optional) [query] [extra parameters] (optional)
- [instruction] - Must contain / succeeded with [a-zA-Z] only
- [query] - Can contain [\w\s()'-] (alphanumeric, whitespace, parentheses, apostrophe, dash)
- [extra parameters] - ~ preceded by whitespace, succeeded with only [a-zA-Z]

String examples that should work:

```
/get D0cUm3nt   ex4Mpl3'  ~now
D0cUm3nt  ex4Mpl3'
/post T(h)(i5  s(h)ou__ld w0rk t0-0'
```

String examples that shouldn't work:

```
//get document~now
~later
example ~now~later
```

Before I pass the string through the regex I trim any whitespace at the start and end of the string (before any text is seen) but I don't trim double whitespaces within the string as some queries require them.

Here is the regex I used:

```
^(/{0,1}[a-zA-Z])?[\w\s()'-]*((\s~[a-zA-Z]*){0,2})?$
```

To break it down slightly:

```
[instruction check] - (/{0,1}[a-zA-Z])?
[query check] - [\w\s()'-]*
[parameter check] - ((\s~[a-zA-Z]*){0,2})?
```

This is the first time I've actually done any serious regex away from a tutorial so I'm wondering **is there anything I can change within my regex to make it more compact/efficient?**

All fresh perspectives are appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Where you say `must be succeeded by` you probably want `+` and not `*`. Also, _StackOverflow_ is more for "What's wrong?" rather than "What's better?"

Comment: @PaulS. - Thanks, good catch. Also, this is a slightly off-topic question, but I've included parentheses within the regex simply for grouping purposes, I don't really need to capture anything within the string via regex, would this affect the checking I'm doing?

Comment: The `?` after a `(..)` means _the previous group is optional_. Similarly for `{x,y}` after `(..)`. If you remove parenthesis these will no longer function as expected. If you don't want to capture, you can use non-capture groups which have the form `(?:pattern)`

Comment: You should provide some examples of Strings than you want to match.

Comment: Regex does no math. There is not if, then, else there. I personally believe that maybe dozens of lines of code (by using switch and some Regex that is less complicated) within a couple of minutes will do the same parsing job. I've been using Regex for quite long time and I never feel dealing with long Regex patterns has anything to do with efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your regex: `^(/{0,1}[a-zA-Z])?[\w\s()'-]*((\s~[a-zA-Z]*){0,2})?$`,

you can change `{0,1}` to `?` that is a shortcut to say 0 or 1 times:

```
^(/?[a-zA-Z])?[\w\s()'-]*((\s~[a-zA-Z]*){0,2})?$
```

The last part is present 0,1 or 2 times, then the `?` is superfluous:

```
^(/?[a-zA-Z])?[\w\s()'-]*(\s~[a-zA-Z]*){0,2}$
```

The first part may be simplified too, the `?` just after the `/` is superfluous:

```
^(/[a-zA-Z])?[\w\s()'-]*(\s~[a-zA-Z]*){0,2}$
```

If you don't use the captured groups, you can change them to non-capture group: `(?: )` that are more efficient

```
^(?:/[a-zA-Z])?[\w\s()'-]*(?:\s~[a-zA-Z]*){0,2}$
```

You can also use the case-insensitive modifier `(?i)`:

```
^(?i)(?:/[a-z])?[\w\s()'-]*(?:\s~[a-z]*){0,2}$
```

Finally, as said in OP, `~` must be followed by `[a-zA-Z]`, so change the last `*` by `+`:

```
^(?i)(?:/[a-z])?[\w\s()'-]*(?:\s~[a-z]+){0,2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks slightly better:

```
^(?:/?[a-zA-Z]*\s)?[\w\s()'-]*(?:\s~[a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more the place for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that capture groups are useful to you:

`^((?:\/|\s~)[a-z]+)?([\w\s()'-]+)(~[a-z]+)?$`

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uK7xL0)

Comment: This matches `-~a` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
var regex = /^((\/)?[a-zA-Z]+)?[\w\s()'-]*((\s~)?[a-zA-Z]+){0,2}$/;
```